# Printing PDF from .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, printing

I have a 5-80 page PDF that is generated by my page. I have this PDF in a byte array, which I could temporarily save to file if need be.

I would prefer to not make the user download then print the PDF. Is there a fairly easy way to allow the user to print this file? Best case is I can somehow print directly from the `byte[]` or a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: The user will have to download the file contents in order to view/print it. Do you mean you don't want the PDF to appear inline in the browser, but that the user is prompted to download it?

Comment: If you want the user to print the file without downloading it you're going to have to mail them a CD or thumb drive.

Comment: Haha. Sorry about the incorrect terminology. I do not want the user to have to save the PDF locally, then find and print that file.

Comment: @PFranchise well that all depends on how their browser is configured then, if it loads it into the browser they can print from there, no way to know this unless you are in an internal environment where you know the configuration of the machines/browsers

Comment: @libertas ah, that is right. Somehow that fact escaped me when I was approaching this problem. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply `return File(stream, fileName, "application/pdf")` from an MVC action.

The browser will render the PDF using the appropriate plugin, and will (typically) offer a print button.

Comment: Ah, that seems like a great idea. I will try that out now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Quick question: what is the "application/pdf" parameter? Is that the mime type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Controller.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470835.aspx) method to return files

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
{    
   byte[] bytes = GetYourByteArrayForPDF();
   return File(bytes, "application/pdf","somefriendlyname.pdf");    
}
```

Assuming `GetYourByteArrayForPDF` is your method which returns your byte array for the PDF file.

This will provide the file content directly to the browser where user can print/save.

From a web app, you can not simply invoke the print command and print something in the Clients computer. user has to manually do that unless you have some activex control (only IE supports) /browser plugin to do so.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I do have a quick follow-up question if you don't mind. Should I now be able to view my pdf, by going to the URL: "site.com/controller/getFile"?

Comment: I feel like people are confusing his question, or his question confused me... it almost seemed like he was asking how to skip the file download and just go straight to the printer which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @PFranchise no matter what, you're passing a PDF file to the user via HTTP, how the browser handles it depends on the client side configuration, it may pop a download dialogue, load an in browser viewer, etc

Comment: @libertas Ok, thanks for that clarification. This application is going to be used with FF/Chrome exclusively, so they should handle the PDF how I want them to. I am a fairly new web dev, so I really appreciate the information.

Comment: From a web app, you can not simply invoke the print command and print something in the Clients computer. user has to manually do that unless you have some activex control (only IE supports) /browser plugin to do so.